# SQL only want to return a single row for each note

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following tables:
Orders, Notes, Permits

The following columns are in each table:

```
Orders = ID
Notes = ID, RelatedID, Note, Timestamp
Permits = ID, OrderId
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT o.id
     , op.id
     , n.timestamp
  FROM [tblOrders] o
INNER JOIN [tblNotes] n ON n.[RelatedID] = o.[ID]
INNER JOIN [tblPermits] op ON o.[id] = op.[OrderID]
     WHERE n.[Text] LIKE 'Line item is created%'
```

An order has 1 to many permits and a order has 1 to many notes

The problem here is that the notes relate to the order and not the individual permit so when you join o.id with n.relatedID if there is more that 1 permit in an order it will actually show 4 records instead of 2 since it joins twice for each permit since the orderID is the same. How can I get this to only return 2 records?

Comment: You've updated the question to add that you need `tblnotes.timestamp` in the output.  This will duplicate records for every supporting/related record in `tblnotes` - or do you want the highest timstamp per note, or something similar?  Either way, a single value has to be in the output to remove duplicates--it can be a comma separated list if you really want...

Comment: Yes I know sorry forgot that essential detail. I like your answer though it helps with another problem I was having....If I have 2 permits in an order I need to get only 2 notes. The 'Line Item Is Created' Only happens once per permit. Why this is tied to the order and not the permit is BEYOND me trust me!

Comment: @anicolais: Gotcha, sounds like you just need to relate the `permits` table to the `notes` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is using JOINs risks duplication in the resultset because there'll be a record for each supporting record in the `tblnotes`.  My first recommendation is to re-write so you aren't using a JOIN:

### Using EXISTS:

```
SELECT o.id,
       p.id
  FROM tblorders o
  JOIN tblpermits p ON p.orderid = o.id
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM tblnotes n 
               WHERE n.[Text] LIKE 'Line item is created%'
                 AND n.relatedid = o.id)
```

### Using IN:

```
SELECT o.id,
       p.id
  FROM tblorders o
  JOIN tblpermits p ON p.orderid = o.id
 WHERE o.id IN (SELECT n.relatedid
                  FROM tblnotes n 
                WHERE n.[Text] LIKE 'Line item is created%')
```

Comment: +1 For the exists :). I like exists way better. It should outperform and I also find it more readable (that of course is an opinion but still).

Comment: @Joni: Agreed - EXISTS is also more accommodating, most databases don't support tuples (MySQL only one to my knowledge) but you can compare tuples using EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT
o.id
,op.id
.....
....
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I needed the timestamp as well which is different between the 2 notes so would this still work? I tried select distinct but it still did the same thing...

Comment: No, in that case see OMG Ponies' answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  o.id ,op.id
FROM    [tblOrders] o
JOIN    [tblPermits] op
ON      op.[OrderID] = o.[id]
WHERE   o.id IN
        (
        SELECT  n.[RelatedID]
        FROM    tblNotes n
        WHERE   n.[Text] LIKE 'Line item is created%'
        )
```